# Creating a Search Function in PHP

Tags: php, search

**TL;DR**

How can I filter a mega-array based on exploded `$_POST['search']` to match search terms in the database?

**Full spiel**

I'm trying to build a search algorithm but I seem to be getting stuck with terms bigger than one word.

The logic behind it (or desired logic I'm trying to implement) is this:

I have 7 Fields to check against:

> Make 
>   Model 
>   Misc Name 
>   Street Name 
>   ID 
>   CC 
>   Year

When a user only types a single search term it will check against these fields, then filter out the duplicates and return the results. I got it this far and then tried to implement "stricter search" where if the user types something like "Honda XL" then it should only return results with Honda and XL in the rows.

I thought I could use `array_diff` and `array_filter` to achieve this (maybe I can, just not using it correctly) but results still appear with terms that **don't include XL**.

Here are the important parts of my script:

1) individual field search:

```
if (is_numeric($search)) {
    foreach ($numericFields as $key => $field)
    {
        $res = $handler->prepare($sql. '`'. $field .'` LIKE :search');
        $res->execute(array(':search' => '%'. $search[0] .'%'));

        $rows[$key. '-data'] = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
} else {
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field)
    {
        $res = $handler->prepare($sql. '`'. $field .'` LIKE :search');
        $res->execute(array(':search' => '%'. $search[0] .'%'));

        $rows[$key. '-data'] = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

**Note: `$search` is generated by `$search = explode(' ', $_POST['serach']);`**

2) Remove dupe values

```
$rows = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $rows)));
```

3) where I try to match the exploded search terms to the values in the array:

```
foreach ($rows as $result)
{
    $result = array_filter(
        $result,
        function($value)
        {
            return (count(array_diff($value, explode(' ', $_POST['search']))) > 0);
        }
    );

    # then use the $result to build shizzle
}
```

Let's say for examples sake, we keep using `Honda XL` as our search term, but things like `Honda CR` keep returning (and XL doesn't appear anywhere within the string).

So it essentially builds a mega-array of the first search term then uses the other terms to filter down the results. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit: JSON output as req. (generated from search term: Honda XL)**

```
[0…99]
​    0: {…}
​​​        attributes: {…}
​​​​            "data-cc": "600"​​​​
            "data-epid": "219723301"​​
            "data-make": "Honda"
​​​            "data-model": "XL"
​​​​            "data-street": "Transalp"
​​​​            "data-sub": "V"
​​​​            "data-year": "1999"
​​​​        <prototype>: Object { … }
​​​        checked: false
​​​        name: "Honda XL 600 1999 V Transalp"
​​​        value: "219723301"
​​​        <prototype>: Object { … }
​​    1: Object { name: "Honda CR 80 1980 R --", value: "219723391", checked: false, … }
​​    2: Object { name: "Honda SH i 150 2009 D --", value: "219723931", checked: false, … }
​​    3: Object { name: "Honda FJS 400 2012 A Silver Wing", value: "219723971", checked: false, … }
    4: Object { name: "Honda XL 250 1987 R --", value: "219723981", checked: false, … }
```

(only an example as real count of data is >3k)

Comment: could it be this? `explode(' ', $_POST['search'])` that would split your Honda XL string maybe?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I thought I needed to do that - the values aren't stored in the DB as `Honda XL` - each term is a field essentially, but it's pretty counter-intuitive to tell users they must search in a certain order for search to work, so my idea is to take the first term as a base term and then match around that

Comment: is it not easier just making one big query with lots of `OR` clauses?

Comment: @delboy1978uk that's like ... a fudge load of OR clauses, 7 fields = 7 individual searches + 1 + 2 LIKE, 1 + 3 LIKE etc. then 1 + 2 + 3 LIKE etc. upto 7 ... would that not be a huge hit on mysql?

Comment: i guess it depends on how big the db is and how much it has to search through.If you could paste some json arrays of results you get we might be able to help better on the php side

Comment: @delboy1978uk 40196 rows thus far (will continue to grow) and erm, can do lemme add it into my script and post the output :)

Comment: when you say "stricter search", do you allow the user to select 'search on make only, or model only etc?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yeah - that's the point of the 1) snippet of code - they can just search `Honda` and a fuck-off list of Hondas will appear

Comment: @delboy1978uk see updated ^.^

Comment: dude this is heavy might cause you a lot of memory which result to out of memory

Comment: Surely `data-model` contains CR therefore `count(array_diff())` would return 1 for a search term `honda xl` ? I don't see how your current solution is returning `Honda CR` rows unless some of your data contains `XL` in another column, in that case, you should probably change your SQL queries to only pull out the data you **need** for the search, once you find the results then pull out all the information on them

Comment: @Beginner seems to be ok (executes in <2 secs) - but will heed your warning and optimise once it fullly works :)

Comment: @Jaquarh `data-model` is built after the `array_diff` - and why would CR return 1 for Honda XL? - maybe you're right, though the table is more or less exclusively those referenced columns, but s'pose it can't hurt to be more specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_diff` returns 0 if there **are** no differences. We can loop through each of the query results and output the data relevant for search.

```
foreach($rows as $row) { 
    foreach(array_filter($row, function($data) { 
        return count(array_diff(explode(' ', $_POST['search']), $data)) == 0; 
    }) as $data) { 
        var_dump($data); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use mysql `concat` function in query to combine the `make` and `model field and then search the string by`=`operator to do the exact match rather than`LIKE` operator

Comment: I did think of the possibilities of this, but it won't necessarily be make and model, user might just search CC and Year for example - there's no way to fully know what field they're searching

Comment: use concat for these two columns and keep other columns as it is while creating query in loop and add your search operator to match string.

Comment: but what if user doesn't search make model? and searches something like CC and Year? Surely I'd want to dynamically filter based on a base result rather then depend on concatting two columns that might not even be searched for?

Comment: I'm mentioning make all queries that have all the fields using OR operator like `CONCAT('make',' ','model') as manuf ` and in `WHERE` clause use `manuf  LIKE %SEARCH STRING% OR CC LIKE %SEARCH STRING% OR YEAR LIKE %SEARCH STRING%` like that.